# where is the bundle:install command in capistrano deployment rails3.2 app?

Tags: capistrano, bundler, rbenv

I'm trying to deploy a rails 3.2 app using capistrano and rbenv on prod server.

Bundle is failing so I want to override the `bundle:install` callback hook but I couldn't find the method in the capistrano gem sorce.

Where/which file does this declared ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its actually in Bundler.

- Its hooked up to Capistrano here - https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/capistrano.rb#L9
- The install task is defined here -

https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/deployment.rb#L38

Given this, you can experiment around to figure out your problem.

Cheers!